# Will a MOSFET operated above SOA, max. IDM (package limited), survive having the current pulse way narrower than SOA limit?

Tags: mosfet

I am planning to use a protection with a PNP like this (approx.), for a PMOS device (schematic is just for illustration purposes, please ignore it). My transistor is FDMS86163P.

[image]

In my simulations, when a hard short-circuit occurs, everything works well except first 50 ns :))
Until the PMOS is turning OFF there are about 50 ns with ID having 500 A value.
Of course, I cannot have infinite current to discharge the gate, my practical value is few amps.

[image]

Now the SOA for FDMS86163P states (upper region) that package limit (bonding) is 400 A and specify this for 10 us pulses.

But my pulse is 50 ns!

In practice, I'm pretty sure that transistor will survive quite well, but I cannot find anywhere a reasonable explanation for this, nor, some technical (empirical) calculations.

Appreciate any comments!

[image]

Comment: `Please ignore the schematic` Uh? The 317 limits current to a few amps. Does your 50 ns simulation include all that's relevant? Is this a one-off hobby project, or are you a professional designer?

Comment: Guys, like I said, the schematic is just to see how a PNP is connected, has nothing to do with the real one which I cannot post.

Comment: Nota: the safe area is the wide dotted line. Outside this world, no guaranteed to survive ( note that this is done also for the "internal wires", because the "i2 t" or "i2 sqrt(t)" functions are not known for these wires which will act as a "fuse")

Comment: Make sure that your simulation includes at least some of the parasitic inductance. Depending on the layout this might be at least a few nH to tens of nH. This will limit the di/dt and your pulse might be within SOA.

Comment: @orfruit Having a schematic that contains elements not applicable to your situation is confusing and distracting to readers (as evidenced by Neil_UKs comment; I was also confused by the 24V in there). This is a good question that is otherwise well-asked, but I predict you and others will waste energy re-explaining that no, that schematic isn't your actual schematic. Your question is much better off with a more representative schematic. Not being able to show your full circuit is no excuse; you can replace source and load with black boxes with some specs like nominal current and voltage.

Comment: Get rid of the current and inapplicable schematic and show the sim schematic.

Comment: What is the frequency of these pulses ?

Comment: @Lars Hankeln, indeed, 100nH just made the peak to be 250A that falls in SOA. This still not explains how to judge this, otherways that like for a fuse (for vond wires). Thank you

Comment: Here an example for firing "wire bond" : https://www.onsemi.com/site/pdf/IMAPS-wirefuse_aditi_roger.pdf

Comment: This will also help a little : http://www.irf.com/technical-info/appnotes/an-1140.pdf

Comment: @Antonio51 thank you very much for these documents